# mod_wsgi items saved in wrong order

Tags: python, asynchronous, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get a grip on mod_wsgi by writing a simple WSGI server running under Apache on Linux. However I notice that requests are not always served in the order in which they arrive, even if they come from the same client/browser.

If a page e.g. contains images A and B respectively, A may be served as answer to the request for B, so it is shown at the wrong place. I'm convinced I must be making a very trivial mistake, but I am unable to find out what.

I am aware that the WSGI callable must be reentrant, and by logging requests and responses, I see that indeed it is sometimes entered a second time before the first result is served. But surely when the browser asks for B it should not get A as result from a previous GET. Or am I missing something very fundamental about HTTP?

Global Apache directives:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /home/sterlicht/modWsgi/mod_wsgi.so

Virtual host directives:

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sterlicht/debug/app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong.
My callable was not reentrant after all.
The code in the **call** member of my application class used some instance data, which were overwritten by concurrent invocations.